# Scrollable Content areas on Mobile Safari

Tags: scroll, mobile-safari, area

I'm developing a web app for iOS devices, and want to have a header that stays on the top, and then two scrollable content areas underneath it, kind of like Gmail's iPad interface and the iPad split-view apps. Does anyone know how? I've looked at http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/, which has a good solution to the fixed positioning, but only allows one scrollable content area. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use div scrolling. See [Glovebox](http://blogs.nitobi.com/jesse/2010/05/03/glovebox/) for example. Try this [demo](http://risingj.com/GloveBoxDemo/) on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, just found Sencha Touch, which lets me do this and much, much more!